# Resetting arrays in VS and Xcode have weird timestamp discrepancies

Tags: c, arrays, xcode, visual-studio

**EDIT (09/24/15)**: Added GCC on Ubuntu timestamps

I have a 17-dimensional array (containing exactly 79,626,240 values) that I need reset (to -3) every loop.

I've written a chunk of code to test out using memset and for-loops to reset this array, and logged the average time it takes to reset the array. Comparing the same code block in Xcode and Visual Studio, some very weird results emerge...

Here are my timestamps (the code is appended to the bottom of this post):

```
                   | XCODE 7.0  |  VS 14     |  GCC      |
---------------------------------------------------------
memset (seconds)   | 0.00450 s  |  0.00719 s | 0.01197 s |
for-loop (seconds) | 0.73300 s  |  0.00728 s | 1.08112 s |
```

What is up with the time discrepancies?! Why is memset two orders of magnitude faster than using for-loops in Xcode, but in Visual Studio, they functionally take the exact same time?

The code is below. `compiletable_main` uses for-loops to reset the array, while `compiletable_main_3` uses memset.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define num_runs 10
#define num_gens 4000

#define num_threads 3

////    BEGIN CATABLE STRUCTURE
#define box1 3
#define box2 3
#define box3 3
#define box4 3

#define box5 4
#define box6 4
#define box7 4
#define box8 4

#define memvara 2
#define memvarb 2
#define memvarc 2
#define memvard 2

#define tdirect 1
#define adirect 4
#define outputnum 15
#define fs 2
#define bs 2

typedef struct calookup
{

    signed char n[box1][box2][box3][box4][box5][box6][box7][box8][memvara][memvarb][memvarc][memvard][adirect][tdirect][fs][bs][outputnum];


} calookup;

////    END CATABLE STRUCTURE     

int ra_pos = 0;
long int dimensions = box1*box2*box3*box4*box5*box6*box7*box8*memvara*memvarb*memvarc*memvard*adirect*tdirect*fs*bs*outputnum;


// Compiletable_main
void compiletable_main(calookup *lookup) {

    int i, j, k, l, m, nb, o, p, na, nx, ny, nx1, naa, nbb;
    int x, y, z, zz, xa, xb, xc, xd, ncc, ndd;


    for (j = 0;j < box1; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < box2; k++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < box3; l++)
            {
                for (m = 0; m < box4; m++)
                {
                    for (x = 0;x < box5; x++)
                    {
                        for (y = 0; y < box6; y++)
                        {
                            for (xa = 0;xa < box7; xa++)
                            {
                                for (xb = 0; xb < box8; xb++)
                                {
                                    for (nb = 0; nb < memvara; nb++)
                                    {
                                        for (na = 0; na < memvarb; na++)
                                        {
                                            for (nx = 0; nx < memvarc; nx++)
                                            {
                                                for (nx1 = 0; nx1 < memvard; nx1++)
                                                {
                                                    for (naa = 0; naa < adirect; naa++)
                                                    {
                                                        for (nbb = 0; nbb < tdirect; nbb++)
                                                        {
                                                            for (ncc = 0; ncc < fs; ncc++)
                                                            {
                                                                for (ndd = 0; ndd < bs; ndd++)
                                                                {
                                                                    for (o = 0; o < outputnum; o++)
                                                                    {
                                                                        lookup->n[j][k][l][m][x][y][xa][xb][nb][na][nx][nx1][naa][nbb][ncc][ndd][o] = -3;     //set to default value
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                               }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void compiletable_main_3(calookup *lookup) {

    memset(lookup->n, -3, (dimensions*sizeof(signed char)));

}

void evaluatepopulation_tissueb(calookup *rs) {

    //    Swap between compiletable_main_3 and compiletable_main
    //      for the memset and for-loop approaches, respectively

    compiletable_main_3(rs);

}

calookup ra;

int main() {

    printf(" Begin program... \n");

    static double time_consumed = 0;
    static double avg_time = 0;
    clock_t start, end;

    int i;
    int i_max = 100;

    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < i_max; i++) {

        evaluatepopulation_tissueb(&ra);
    }

    end = clock();

    time_consumed = (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    avg_time = time_consumed / i_max;

    printf("Completed run \n");
    printf(" Total Time : %lf \n ", time_consumed);
    printf(" Avg Time/Loop : %lf \n", avg_time);

    //sleep(70000);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The for loop in main is probably getting optimised away in 3 out of your 4 test cases.

Comment: @PaulR Can you elucidate more?

Comment: Put `main()` in a separate .c file and link it with your test functions - that way the timing loop won't be optimised away. Also make sure you have the same optimisation level for all tests (e.g. `-O3`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C has a long list of compilers developed by different organisations & individuals [check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers)

These compilers vary a lot it the techniques they would employ for optimization & many other stuffs . Visual Studio and XCode being from different Tech Giants you should not expect them to use the same compiler.

A basic google Search Revealed that Apple supports LLVM/Clang which offers complete replacement for GCC

Microsoft uses a different one.
Thus you might notice a total time taken difference.
Try running your code on GCC or TCC ! You should again get different answers.

Result on GCC for the code you uploaded :

[image: Notice Different Answers]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @paulR he is asking about the time discrepancies when running the code on different editors i precisely answered that

Comment: I think you missed the point - there is a 100x discrepancy - the reason is most likely due to the compiler optimising away the timing loop in some of the cases, i.e. it's not just a small discrepancy due to different compilers.

Comment: @Rahul This may indeed be the case...time stamping in GCC (on Ubuntu) shows for-loop times of 1.0811 seconds and memset times of 0.011968 seconds